# How to create records on different model by making onchange method?

Tags: python, odoo-10

Hope you are doing well. I need a little favour from you. I have made a function on Onchange Method. I want,if I onchange the field i.e.final_unique_id, then it create a Model which is in different Module. But It is not working on onchange the field. It is working on page refreshing and saving the form. Please help me out.

```
@api.multi    
@api.onchange('final_unique_id')    
def finish_serial_no(self):
             vals = {
                       'name': self.production_id.name,
                       'work_order_id':self._origin.id,
                       'product_id':self.product_id.id,
                       'unique_number':self.final_unique_id,
                       'date': datetime.datetime.now(),
                       'info_date': datetime.datetime.now(),
                       'user': self.env.user.id,
                       'status': 'Done',
                   }
                   res = self.env['info.module'].create(vals)
```

Comment: i can see you are assigning the value but then nothing is being returned or called so nothing happens. but then you reload the 'res' that you assigned gets called with the updated value.

Comment: @mohsinali, Thanks for answer. I returned res also and returned True also. But found to copy paste. But it is not creating recording.

Comment: @mohsinali, and when I return res. It's given me error:- 

AttributeError: 'info.module' object has no attribute 'get'. Please check and let me know if you have any question.

Comment: yes because its referencing to the self an instance of a class which uses get and set function. i will have to apologies i wont be much help any futher.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is wrong, you are creating a record in `'info.module'`
that have a many2one `work_order_id` to the current model, you need to know
before saving the record the id is an instance of `NewId` witch is a dummy class, so when you create the record it will not attached to the current record because it's not
yet saved it it has no **ID** (`self._origin.id` while creating the record will not work, it only if it is saved)

you are saying that it creates the record after saving
and refreshing a page I am assuming that you have a `one2many` field to `'info.module'`
**[if you don't have one create it, if you 
don't need the user to see it just hide it in the view]**, let's assume it is called `info_module_id`:

```py
    @api.onchange('final_unique_id')    
    def finish_serial_no(self):
        vals = {
                   'name': self.production_id.name,
                   # 'work_order_id':self._origin.id, this will be handled by the one2many when you save the record
                   'product_id': self.product_id.id,
                   'unique_number': self.final_unique_id,
                   'date':  datetime.datetime.now(),
                   'info_date': datetime.datetime.now(),
                   'user': self.env.user.id,
                   'status': 'Done',
               }
        # Use `new` instead of create this will create the record but doesn't save it in database. 
        self.ifo_module_id |= self.env['info.module'].new(vals) # add the record to one2many using `|` operator
```

It's not advised to created a record in `onchange` method because User can always click on **discard** button. I hope this helps you

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I did that already and tested. it is assigning :- info.module(<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f16accdf9d0>, to self.info_module_id.

That is why, I have taken self._origin.id. Because on onchange self._origin contains id of the record. Can I proceed this with ajax call because I donot want to refresh the page. Please help me if possible. I would be grateful to you.

Comment: What do you want exactly?!! You want to add a record in a one2many field?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, I need to add records on One2many field while onchange the field.        Please let me know if you have any question. Thanks

Comment: I just showed how??? Did you try what I suggested what is the name of you one2many field?

Comment: Yes, I tried that you have told me. The name of One2many field is info_module_id, as suggested by you. But it is getting value as info.module(<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f16accdf9d0>. That is why I have used _origin.id for create a record on onchange function. It was creating the record but only on refreshing the page and save the page. But I need at the time of onchangiing the field. 

Please suggest other methodology in Odoo. Which I can do for this type of concern?

Comment: Did you use my code as it is?!!!! Because you cannot create a record in info model before you save the current record, can you post the code that you tried? Because my solution should work and you are doing something wrong